# R -> Sum part of Columns + agreggating observations

Tags: r, sum, filtering

I am very new to coding and just started doing some R graphics and now I am kinda lost with my data analyse and need some light! I am training some analyses and I got a very long dataset with 19 Countries x 12 months x 22 Products and for every month a Profit. Kinda like this:

```
Country   Month   Product Profit
Brazil    Jan     A      50
Brazil    fev     A      80
Brazil    mar     A      15
Austria   Jan     A      35
Austria   fev     A      80
Austria   mar     A      47
France    Jan     A      21
France    fev     A      66
France    mar     A      15
[...]
France    Dez     C      40 etc...
```

I am was thinking to do one graph showing the profits through the year and another for every country, so I could see the top and bottom 2 countries. I wanted to have something like:

```
All Countries   Jan   106        or     Brazil   2021   145
All Countries   Fev   146               Austria  2021   162
All Countries   Mar   77                France   2021   112
```

but the sum function can't help with characters type and as I have a long List, idk how to sum only part of the column.

sorry if it got confusing.

Comment: Hi Ikasquilici, does the reply answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using **base R**, you can try something along these lines.

```
# sum of profit per month
out1 <- tapply(df$Profit, df$Month, sum)

# sum of profit per year per country
out2 <- data.frame(
  profit = sapply(split(df, f = ~ df$Country + df$Year), function(x) sum(x$Profit))
)
out2$Country <- gsub('\\.[0-9]*', '', rownames(out2))
out2$Year <- gsub('[a-zA-z]*\\.', '', rownames(out2))
rownames(out2) <- NULL
```

**Output**

```
> out1
Apr Aug Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar May Sep 
105 198 240 150  63 141  45 240  45 

> head(out2)
  profit Country Year
1    162 Austria 2019
2    145  Brazil 2019
3    102  France 2019
4    162 Austria 2020
5    145  Brazil 2020
6    102  France 2020
```

**Data**

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(
  Country = rep(c(rep('Brazil',3L),rep('Austria',3L),rep('France',3L)), 3L),
  Profit = rep(c(50,80,15,35,80,47,21,66,15), 3L),
  Month = rep(c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep'),3L),
  Year = sort(rep(c(2019,2020,2021), 9L))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `dplyr` has quite a natural syntax for this:

```r
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- data.frame(
  Country = rep(c(rep("Brazil", 3L), rep("Austria", 3L), rep("France", 3L)), 3L),
  Profit = rep(c(50, 80, 15, 35, 80, 47, 21, 66, 15), 3L),
  Month = rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"), 3L),
  Year = sort(rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), 9L))
)
df %>%
  group_by(Country, Month) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(Profit))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Country'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   Country [3]
#>   Country Month   sum
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Austria Apr     105
#> 2 Austria Jun     141
#> 3 Austria May     240
#> 4 Brazil  Feb     240
#> 5 Brazil  Jan     150
#> 6 Brazil  Mar      45
#> 7 France  Aug     198
#> 8 France  Jul      63
#> 9 France  Sep      45
```